# Add right-click context menu to invoke a RAR command, pipe to clipboard?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, explorer, rar

I need to implement a tool so I can right-click on a .RAR file in the Windows File Explorer, an additional context menu item will launch rar.exe with the file as a argument for a command line command. The output text should be piped into the windows clipboard.

I know there are many tutorials for manipulating the Windows Explorer Context Menu but none jump at me as a solution. Also the syntax of the batch command with the special characters has got me puzzled!

The default home for rar.exe is **C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe**
The command is either **rar.exe L[t,b] file | clip** *or* **rar.exe V[t,b] file | clip**

Environment:
Windows 7, Home Premium
batch commands only, no other languages.

Answer (score 2):

These are our standards in Windows.

The following table describes the notation used to indicate command-line syntax.

```
Notation  Description  
Text without brackets or braces
 Items you must type as shown

<Text inside angle brackets>
 Placeholder for which you must supply a value

[Text inside square brackets]
 Optional items

{Text inside braces}
 Set of required items; choose one

Vertical bar (|)
 Separator for mutually exclusive items; choose one

Ellipsis (…)
 Items that can be repeated
```

So the `v` one of them can be

```
rar -v etc
rar -vt etc
rar -vb etc
```

From my website. Note `\\` for `\` and `\"` for `"`. Also this is windows 98. Use `CMD.exe` instead of `command.com` on NT.

**Print a Directory Listing**

This registry file will add an item to the context menu for file directories to print or list all files or directories in a directory.

To add a command to the context menu to print a directory listing.

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Print\Command]
@="command.com /c dir \"%1\"> Prn
```

To add a command to the context menu to print a directory listing to a file on the desktop.

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\List\Command]
@="command.com /c dir \"%1\"> c:\\windows\\desktop\\Dirlist.txt"
```

A single > replaces the file while a double > adds to the file. The format of the listing will be determined by the dircmd environment setting or add switches after the dir in the command line.

Type Dir /? in a MS-Dos Prompt window to see the options. Use Set in either config.sys or autoexec.bat to set the default options,ie,

```
Set DIRCMD=/a /v /l /4
```

If using the DIRCMD environmental variable prefix it with a hyphen to turn off. The next reg file prints only directories and sub directories without the verbose (/v) settings.

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Print Tree\Command]
@="command.com /c dir /-v /a:d /s \"%1\"> Prn
```